# Using numpy, how can I generate an array where the value at each index is the sum of the values from 0 to that same index in a second array?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array a=[3,5,7]

How can I efficiently generate a second array b, where b[i] = numpy.Sum(a[0:i]?

I've looked through the numpy docs but the solution isn't jumping out at me...

The expected output would be b=[3,8,15]

Any ideas will be gratefully received!!!

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) function from numpy here:

```
a=np.array([3,5,7])

In [1]: np.cumsum(a)
Out[1]: array([ 3,  8, 15], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct - that's exactly what I was looking for, Not sure how I missed that from the docs....